# How do I look for the right class and id for parsing a page?

Tags: python

This is the code i have so far, i'm attempting to get the subscriber count.
This is this the error I get:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

I hope someone can help!

```py
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests as r

    url = r.get("https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC57EgpLB1Q0tXc5tWDhttoQ)
    soup_content = BeautifulSoup(url.content, 'html.parser')
    id_ = soup_content.find(id="meta")
    class_ = id_.find_all(class_="style-scope ytd-c4-tabbed-header-renderer")
    hopefully_it_works = class_[0]
    print(hopefully_it_works.prettify())
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find\_all'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23186484/python-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

Comment: not really (or im 2 dumb to understand it) but i did look at it before i posted this

Answer (score 0):

the BS and web scraping is not the correct way how to get the youtube data.
Please, consider using the official youtube api, which provides these data you need and much more :)
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/

you can try your requests here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#try-it

in your case you need to fill:
part: statistics
id: UC57EgpLB1Q0tXc5tWDhttoQ
(https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channelspart=statistics&id=channel_id&key=your_key)

the response is

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
  "etag": "eQRUDH-2j1eYIpexSuSOsz12tc8",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1,
    "resultsPerPage": 1
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#channel",
      "etag": "D-yZ896UMFRcDDSrfATBaiygDkc",
      "id": "UC57EgpLB1Q0tXc5tWDhttoQ",
      "statistics": {
        "viewCount": "9",
        "commentCount": "0",
        "subscriberCount": "3",
        "hiddenSubscriberCount": false,
        "videoCount": "1"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

edit:
if you really want to use BS, there is your solution:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests as r

content = r.get("https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC57EgpLB1Q0tXc5tWDhttoQ")
soup = bs(content.content, "html.parser")
channel_subscribers = soup.find("span", attrs={"class": "channel-header-subscription-button-container yt-uix-button-subscription-container with-preferences"}).find("span", attrs={"class": "yt-subscription-button-subscriber-count-branded-horizontal subscribed yt-uix-tooltip"}).text
print(channel_subscribers)
```

Comment: idk what the language your using is, also i was just practicing web scraping and i wanted a actual practical use so i thought "subscribers for a yt channel" was a good one. And does my code not work in a serious way (like everything about it is wrong?) or a not so serious way (like 1 or 2 lines/tweaks)?

Comment: see the updated answer. I hope this is what you want :)

Comment: thanks :) yeah i probably wont try web scraping again but i thought that i might want to try it and add it a list of topics that i can bring up in a conversation.

Comment: web scrapping is interesting and useful thing, but always try to use api for these things. If there is no api provided, the web scrapping is the way to go :) If I answered your question, feel free to tag it as answer :) thanks!